# Getting the used space for a remote UNC path

Tags: c#

I am developing a small part of an application that should be able to determine how much space a folder on a remote server is taking up. I found post on the GetDiskFreeSpaceEx function, and that works like a charm for my mapped drives. But when I supply a UNC path \server\share\folder\ it fails with a win32 error 1326.

This, I can see, has to do with credentials. The funny thing is, that if I open the UNC path either through the command promp or through the explorer, I can see the files and see how much space they take up. What am I missing? I have seen a post where somebody needed to run the code as the admin for it to work.. but surely, there must be another way?

HH

Comment: Post some code, it will make it easier for us to help :)

Comment: Are you making sure that the UNC path you pass to GetDiskFreeSpaceEx has a trailing backslash (e.g. L"\\\\MyServer\\SomeShare\\")?

Comment: This is the code implemented

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern bool GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(string lpDirectoryName,
       out ulong lpFreeBytesAvailable,
       out ulong lpTotalNumberOfBytes,
       out ulong lpTotalNumberOfFreeBytes);

Comment: protected ulong UsedSpace(string path) {
        ulong freeBytesAvail;
        ulong totalNumOfBytes;
        ulong totalNumOfFreeBytes;

        if (!GetDiskFreeSpaceEx(path, out freeBytesAvail, out totalNumOfBytes, out totalNumOfFreeBytes))
            Client.Log.Add(LogType.Error, string.Format("Win32 Error ({2}) occurred when requesting directory size for {0}, customer {1}.", path, Client.CustomerInfo.Name, Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()));
        else
            return (totalNumOfBytes - totalNumOfFreeBytes)/(1024*1024);
        return 0;
    }

Comment: The call to the GetDiskFreeSpaceEx method fails with an error 1326 which is unknown user/password.

Is it nessesary to impersonate the domain admin in order to do this?

Comment: Okay, I you put the code into a console app, it works... no errors. But, it only returns the usedspace for the share.. not for the full UNC path entered. So if I enter \\server\share\lib1\, it disregards the lib1... even though it exists.